# Не добавляется 0 в jquery.mask

Tags: jquery

Хочу сделать маску ( https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin ) для номера телефона, чтобы всегда в поле было **+70** а дальше уже пользователь мог ввести любые свои цифры.

Делаю так:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#ph').mask('+70 000-000-00-00');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input id="ph" />
```

Но в итоге получается что постоянно есть только +7, а дальше можно вводить любые цифры...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените глобальные настройки. Переназначьте `0` на другой символ, а сам `0` удалите оттуда.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $.jMaskGlobals.translation["d"] = $.jMaskGlobals.translation["0"];
  delete $.jMaskGlobals.translation["0"];
  
  $("#ph").mask('+70 ddd-ddd-dd-dd')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input id="ph" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$('#ph').mask("+7z 000 000", {
  translation: {
    'z': {
      pattern: /[0]/, optional: false
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: сработало, но 0 сам не появляется, хотя другие символы кроме него не пропускает. но нужно чтобы +70 там было всегда

Comment: С такой ситуацией с $.mask() не сталкивался. Но делал так: ставил border: 0 для input, перед ним писал span с нужным текстом (например, "+70") и вокруг них ставил div. В итоге выглядело, как будто это цельный Input.